# When using 'rails new', how do I specify bcrypt to be uncommented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile

If one does not use a `.railsrc` or a template.rb file, `rails new` creates a default Gemfile.

In the default Gemfile, `bcrypt`, among others like `therubyracer`, `unicorn`, and `capistrano-rails`, are commented out.  What do you pass `rails new` to have it generate the Gemfile with any one of them uncommented?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can without a template (I could be wrong), but why don't you just uncomment it yourself? If you are trying to automate something, you can write a script that finds that line in the Gemfile and removes the comment...

Comment: With a template, gems are appended to any section specified.  Adding an uncommented line for `bcrypt` or any of the other commented gems is less than ideal.  Uncommenting the line is fine too but can be a hassle if I want to have more commands run by my template.